# log4j not working correctly in JAX-WS with Spring

Tags: java, web-services, log4j, websphere, jax-ws

I setup a JAX-WS with Spring , everthing works except the log4j  :

I am following The offical sping document : 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-export-servlet

which with Endpoint defined like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

@WebService(serviceName="AccountService")
public class AccountServiceEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

@Autowired
private AccountService biz;

@WebMethod
public void insertAccount(Account acc) {
   biz.insertAccount(acc);
}
```

then I tried to write log in the impl of AccountService :

```
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
    private static Logger logger =   Logger.getLogger(AccountServiceImpl.class.getName()); 
     ... 
     public void insertAccount(Account acc) {
         logger.debug("someting... " ) 
         ....
     }   
 }
```

and in web.xml

```
<context-param>   
 <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>   
 <param-value>classpath:my_log4j.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>   
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

I have tested my_log4j.xml, the configuration is absolute  correct, and I also got log at startup that shows my_log4j.xml was loaded before the WebApplicationContext init

I am wondering if it is bescause the WebService is runing out of Spring then the log4jConfigLocation is not working

The server I am using is Websphere Application Server 7.0

Comment: Does one of your dependencies have Log4j as a dependency?

Comment: yes, sure , I can see the log4j jar in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: This is not what I asked. Is there any OTHER dependency in your project which also uses log4j?

Comment: oh, sorry, and for your question I think no, as this app works quit well  before without log4j

Comment: that doesn't mean anything. We usually have this problem when some internal log4j configuration conflicts with the project's log4j configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally fixed by changing the class loader policy to PARENT_LAST, question closed

Comment: FYI, that should be the last resort, and there usually is another way to get log4j working with 3rd-party libs under WebSphere.